# How to relativity branch with STM32 asm?

Tags: stm32, assembler

I learning STM32 assembler with the STM32CubeIDE and the Nucleo-F103RB. I want to relativity jump with an assembly instruction. I mean, I whant to write something like "*JMP -6*" and the program counter decrease by 6 from current position.

I [have read](https://community.arm.com/arm-community-blogs/b/architectures-and-processors-blog/posts/branch-and-call-sequences-explained) that
*A relative branch is one where the target address is calculated based on the value of the current pc (program counter). Given the example above, an assembler would work out that the target label is eight bytes ahead of the b target instruction (in Arm code) and then generate a relative branch which means 'jump forward by eight bytes'.*
There is a table in this article. In this table the B instruction defined as "*relative*".

So I try this code:

```
  LDR R0, =0x00000000
  LDR R1, =0x0000FFFF
  LDR R2, =GPIOA_ODR

  STR R1, [R2]
  STR R0, [R2]
  B -4
```

But it does't work.

When I rewrite this code like this:

```
  LDR R0, =0x00000000
  LDR R1, =0x0000FFFF
  LDR R2, =GPIOA_ODR

  loop:
  STR R1, [R2]
  STR R0, [R2]
  B loop
```

...and start debug step-by-step with the opened disassembly window.
In the disassembly window I see that the "B" instruction changes to the "b.n":

```
0800158 b.n 0x8000154 <loop>
```

So the question is can I execute a relative jump (or branch) without label with fixed address?
Can I set the relative shift from current program counter value with some constant value like -6 or +8 or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the question is can I execute a relative jump (or branch) without
> label with fixed address? Can I set the relative shift from current
> program counter value with some constant value like -6 or +8 or
> something like that?

Yes. You can use `.` to represent the current address, plus an offset like this:-

```
    b.n .      /* branch back to current address*/      
    b.n .+8    /* branch forward to current address + 8 /*
```

Which generates the following code:-

```
08000158 e7fe    b.n 08000158
0800015a e002    b.n 08000162
```

However this not recommended because calculating the correct offset by hand is tricky. Better to let the assembler do it for you. If you want to avoid cluttering up your code with labels for 'trivial' cases then use macros with labels terminated with `\@:` to generate a new label name on each invocation.

[Here's](https://software-dl.ti.com/codegen/docs/tiarmclang/rel1_3_0_LTS/gnu_syntax_arm_asm_language/gnu_arm_macros.html) an example:-

```
/* COMPARE64 macro definition - GNU-syntax */
        .macro COMPARE64, x_hi, x_lo, y_hi, y_lo
        CMP \x_hi, \y_hi
        BNE .L_\@
        CMP \x_lo, \y_lo
.L_\@:
        .endm

/* COMPARE64 macro invocation */
COMPARE64 r3, r2, r1, r0
```

Which on the first invocation expands to this:-

```
        CMP r3, r1
        BNE .L_0
        CMP r2, r0
.L_0:
```